# Set storyboard ID programmatically for custom UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, compiler-errors

I have created a new class which is a custom `UIViewController`.

I am going to use two of this custom `UIViewController` with a `UIPageViewController` so that I can swipe between them left and right.

I have problems getting this to work due to the nature of setting the `Storyboard ID` programmatically of each custom `UIViewController`

As you can see in the code below, I never get past the point which I've marked with a comment, as I get the following the error:
`Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7f9f404174c0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'id_AssetViewer_A'`

**NOTICE:** I need to set the `Storyboard ID` programatically, **not from the editor!**

My code:

```
   UIPageViewController *pageController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"BrowserPageController"];
    pageController.dataSource = self;

    [[pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    assetViewer_A = [[AssetViewer alloc] init];
    assetViewer_A = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"id_AssetViewer_A"]; //<< error occurs here!
    assetViewer_A.view.tag = 0;

    assetViewer_B = [[AssetViewer alloc] init];
    assetViewer_B = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"id_AssetViewer_B"];
    assetViewer_B.view.tag = 0;


    NSArray *startingViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject: assetViewer_A];
    [pageController setViewControllers: startingViewControllers
                             direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                              animated: NO
                            completion: nil];


    self.browserViewController = pageController;
    [self addChildViewController: self.browserViewController];
    [self.view addSubview: self.browserViewController.view];
    [self.browserViewController didMoveToParentViewController: self];

    if ([pageController.view.subviews.firstObject isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        browserPageView_as_ScrollView = (UIScrollView *)pageController.view.subviews.firstObject;
        browserPageView_as_ScrollView.delegate = self;
    }
```

**PS:** The `Storyboard ID` needs to be **defined by code**, not by hand inside the visual editor.

Comment: you are overwritting your variable just after instantiating it, either do `assetViewer_B = [[AssetViewer alloc] init];` or `assetViewer_B = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"id_AssetViewer_B"];` if your goal is to instantiate a ViewController from the storyboard then remove the `[[AssetViewer alloc] init]`

Comment: `alloc init` works, but  `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` because I haven't set the storyboard of `assetViewer_A` yet. I need to set the Storyboard ID first, and then I can call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. Note: I need to set the Storyboard ID programatically, not from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Define the asset view controller once in your storyboard and give it a Storyboard ID of "id_assetViewer".

Then use this ID in your code in both places where you instantiate your asset viewers (A and B).

There is no need to use different Storyboard IDs.

Comment: I need to do it programatically. I don't want to use the visual editor to define Storyboard ID. In other words: Storyboard ID of the two viewcontrollers need to be defined by code, not by man.

Comment: OK, but you haven't explained why. It's not necessary in order to get your example code working.

Comment: No I know it's not necessary, I just want to. I don't like spending time in a graphical enviroment. That's my preference. But, it's not only my preference that is at play here, I want to do it that way because I want to create different custom UIViewControllers by code.

Comment: So don't get me wrong now, but your answer doesn't really answer my  question. It says in the title that I want to do it programatically.